# Create a slideshow of images in which the image changes every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

Can you help me a little, please? I have no experience with JavaScript yet. I would like to change images every 5 seconds, but the buttons remain functional (ie when I press them, change the image, even if the 5 seconds have not yet passed). Thank you very much!

```
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor</div>
                <img src="imagini/driving1.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor</div>
                <img src="imagini/driving6.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor</div>
                <img src="imagini/driving3.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor</div>
                <img src="imagini/driving2.jpg">
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        </section>

        <div class="dots" >
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
        </div>

        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }

            </script>
```

Comment: use setInterval to call a function that both manages the current slideIndex value and calls showSlides(n) - your button can call the same - but will need to reset the interval 
 use cancelInterval (re: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: You shouldn't use span.

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves exactly what you want. Every time a news slide is set the old timer gets invalidated and a new one is initiated. The timer will run the `plusSlides` function every 5 seconds. Hope this code helps you:

```html
<section>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor 1</div>
            <img src="imagini/driving1.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor 2</div>
            <img src="imagini/driving6.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor 3</div>
            <img src="imagini/driving3.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="titlu">Traffic Signs Tutor 4</div>
            <img src="imagini/driving2.jpg">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </section>

    <div class="dots" >
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
    </div>

    <script>
        //timer
        var newSlide;

        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n = +1) {
          slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
          showSlides(slideIndex);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
          //invalidate old timer
          clearInterval(newSlide);

          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";  
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

          //set a new interval
          newSlide = setInterval(plusSlides, 5000);
        }

   </script>
```